# Using join() vs. wait() thread java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to make sequence of threads. They need to start in order like this:

`A then B then C and finally D.`

When D is finished then C can finish then B, then A.

In this situation what is better to use `join()` threads or `wait()`? and why?

My threads need to start and print the message `Hello I'm thread a/b/c/d` and when they are finished they need to print `I'm finished a/b/c/d`.

Comment: The two things really aren't related.

Comment: I guess you are trying to pause execution of a thread.. Please go through Oracle java tutorial on Threads http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: @BrianRoach can you explane me that? What should i use in this case maybe something else?

Comment: If you have four threads that aren't "allowed" to do things until some condition in the other threads, then you probably shouldn't be multithreading.

Comment: @AurA i guess this will put them just to sleep for some time, but i want them to wait until D is finished then then rest of them can quit.

Comment: @njamanjam Are you sure your example is correct? Your output seems to be wrong.

Comment: @HenryKeiter my task says me to do this program. :/ I'm learning threads and trying to figure this out.

Comment: @njamanjam I'd use `join()` because when you `wait()`, you send a message with "Im done" and then shut down the thread. `join()` does that for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are waiting for the 'other' thread to complete (i.e. finish execution), `join()` would be the better choice.

The javadoc for `join()` says simply: *Waits for this thread to die.*

The mechanism is then relatively simple:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello I'm thread " + getName());
            if (otherThread != null) {
                while (otherThread.isAlive()) {
                    try {
                        otherThread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // ignore
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("I'm finished " + getName());
        }
```

To explain: you need to have a reference to the `otherThread`. So `a` refers to `b`, `b` refers to `c`, `c` refers to `d` and `d` doesn't refer to any `otherThread` (it's null).

The statement `otherThread.join()` waits for the other thread to complete. It is wrapped in a loop since `join()` can throw `InterruptedException` (though rarely in practise).

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: otherThread.join() will itself check for otherthread.isAlive(), this code is redundant and not necessary - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.join%28long%29

Comment: @Naren as mentioned in the `Javadoc` for [guarded blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) - `Note: Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true. `, I think his implemenation is right.

Comment: Ah!, like so... thank you @yadav_vi, was helpful

Comment: I tried this, but this didn't worked out. the sequence of starting and finishing was different every time.

Answer (score 11):

Bearing in mind that `join` and `wait` do very different things and aren't really related, and also bearing in mind that the example you gave is really, really strange, either choice could potentially be the one you're looking for.

`join` is probably the easier choice. The thread calling `join` will wait until the other thread has finished execution. So, each thread in this case will need to hold a reference to the *next* thread, and it'll call `join` right before printing "I'm finished". So your class might look like this:

```
class JoiningThread extends Thread {
    // NOTE: UNTESTED!

    private String name;
    private Thread nextThread;

    public JoiningThread(String name) {
        this(name, null);
    }

    public JoiningThread(String name, Thread other) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nextThread = other;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello I'm thread ".concat(getName()));
        if (nextThread != null) {
            while(nextThread.isAlive()) {
                try {
                    nextThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore this
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("I'm finished ".concat(getName()));
    }
}
```

And the main method could be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread d = WaitingThread("d");
    Thread c = WaitingThread("c", d);
    Thread b = WaitingThread("b", c);
    Thread a = WaitingThread("a", b);

    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
    d.start();

    try {
        a.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

---

What `wait` does is suspend the execution of a thread until `notify` or `notifyAll` is called. So to implement this idea with `wait`, you need each thread to hold a reference to the thread *before* it. The strategy is for the `run` method to finish with a call to `wait`, followed by a call to `notify` the previous thread that execution has finished. So your class might look something like this:

```
class WaitingThread extends Thread {
    // NOTE: UNTESTED!

    private Thread previousThread;
    private String name;

    public WaitingThread(String name) {
        this(name, null);
    }

    public WaitingThread(String name, Thread other) {
        this.name = name;
        this.previousThread = other;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello I'm thread ".concat(getName()));
        // Do other things if required

        // Wait to be woken up
        while(true) {
            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore this
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("I'm finished ".concat(getName()));

        // Wake up the previous thread
        if (previousThread != null) {
            synchronized(previousThread) {
                previousThread.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `main` method that sets everything up from the main thread might be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread a = WaitingThread("a");
    Thread b = WaitingThread("b", a);
    Thread c = WaitingThread("c", b);
    Thread d = WaitingThread("d", c);

    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
    d.start();

    while(true) {
        // wake up d once it goes to sleep
        if (d.isAlive()) {
            d.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is holding of the reference to the next thread handled by the java framework?

Answer (score 5):

The `join()` method is used to wait for a thread to complete execution. The `join()` method of a Thread instance can be used to "join" the start of a thread's execution to the end of another thread's execution so that a thread will not start running until another thread has ended. If `join()` is called on a Thread instance, the currently running thread will block until the Thread instance has finished executing.

[An example of `join()`](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-threads-join-method.html)

The `wait()` method is used to wait for a notification to be sent on an object. The two conditions are pretty distinctive.

[An example and more explanation of `wait()`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ315_016.htm)

Comment: what do you think is better join() or wait() ?

Comment: @njamanjam Neither one is "better"; the two aren't really comparable.

Comment: Yeah the example you give in the question is the most strange one...

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
public class Test1 extends Thread {
    static Object lock = new Object();
    static int n;
    int i;
    String name;

    Test1(String name, int i) {
        this.name = name;
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (i != n) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(name + " started");
            n++;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (i != n - 4) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(name + " finished");
            n++;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Test1("a", 0).start();
        new Test1("b", 1).start();
        new Test1("c", 2).start();
        new Test1("d", 3).start();
    }
}
```

output

```
a started
b started
c started
d started
a finished
b finished
c finished
d finished
```