# countdown multiple threads java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 4 threads witch are printing numbers from 15 to 0.I want  to control executing of my threads for example I want first to thread D to finish and after him thread C and after him thread B and finally thread A. For now they are doing it all parallel.
How can I change that? any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
// Suspending and resuming a thread for Java 2
class NewThread implements Runnable {
   String name; // name of thread
   Thread t;
   boolean suspendFlag;
   NewThread(String threadname) {
      name = threadname;
      t = new Thread(this, name);
      System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
      suspendFlag = false;
      t.start(); // Start the thread
   }
   // This is the entry point for thread.
   public void run() {
      try {
      for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
         System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
         Thread.sleep(200);
         synchronized(this) {
            while(suspendFlag) {
               wait();
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
   }
   void mysuspend() {
      suspendFlag = true;
   }
   synchronized void myresume() {
      suspendFlag = false;
       notify();
   }
}

public class SuspendResume {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      NewThread A = new NewThread("A");
      NewThread B = new NewThread("B");
      NewThread C = new NewThread("C");
      NewThread D = new NewThread("D");
//      try {
//        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
//        System.out.println(A.t.getState());
//        System.out.println(B.t.getState());
//        System.out.println(C.t.getState());
//        System.out.println(D.t.getState());
//        
//        if(D.t.isAlive())
//        {
//            System.out.println("Bla bla bla");
//        }
//            
//        Thread.sleep(1000);
//        A.mysuspend();
//        System.out.println("Suspending thread One");
//        Thread.sleep(1000);
//         A.myresume();
//         System.out.println("Resuming thread One");
//         B.mysuspend();
//         System.out.println("Suspending thread Two");
//         Thread.sleep(1000);
//         B.myresume();
//         System.out.println("Resuming thread Two");
//        
//         
//        
//      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//         System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
//      }
      // wait for threads to finish
      try {
         System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
         A.t.join();
         B.t.join();
         C.t.join();
         D.t.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
      }
      System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why ? the point in using thread is that they run in parallel...

Comment: If you don't want the threads to run in parallel, why would you use threads?

Comment: Why do you want this?  It goes against the whole reason why we write threaded programs which is so they run asynchronously.

Comment: The question why is eligible. But you could achieve this by calling `join()` right after creating the thread. So `NewThread A = NewThread("A"); A.t.join(); NewThread B = NewThread("B"); B.t.join(); // and so on`. Also, you normally write variables with a lower case first letter -> `NewThread a = NewThread("A"); //..`

Comment: @MalaKa  i uploaded my task so that you can understand it better, unfortunately i tried this but it is not solving my problem :( I'm so desperate... I'm trying this for last 10 days...

Comment: This question was already answered (same asker, same problem) over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963396/using-join-vs-wait-thread-java

Answer (score 0):

I think you should design structure of you service class first. I can suggest following:

```
public class Service {

    private List<Service> dependencies;

    // Starts service. 
    // It should wait until all dependencies started using awaitStart method and then start itself
    public void start();

    // Blocks current thread until service is started. 
    // If it is started returns immediately.
    public void awaitStart();

    // Stops service.
    // Awaits until all dependencies are stopped using awaitStop.
    public void stop();

    // Blocks current thread until service is stopped.
    // If it is already stops returns immediately
    public void awaitStop();

    // Actual code that has service specific code.
    // This method may be invoked as last line in 'start' method.  
    public void run();
}
```

Next problem is to implement `start` and `awaitStart` (`stop` methods implemented similar). I recommend to use tools from `java.util.concurrent` for implementing `awaitStart` method. E.g. [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Each service has it's own latch that indicates that server is started. So code for `awaitStart` and `start` is following:

```
private CountDownLatch started = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void awaitStart() {
    started.await();
}

public void start() {
    for (Service service : dependencies) {
        service.awaitStart();
    }
    System.out.println("Service " + name + " is started");
    started.countDown();
    run();
}
```