# Java thread join method calls wait on which object?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java multi threading and little confused with how Java join and wait works.

I have the following example

```
public class Main {

    private static int counter;

    static class RunnableThread implements Runnable {
        private static final String PREFIX = "RT-";
        public RunnableThread() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            counter++;
            System.out.println(PREFIX+counter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread rt = new Thread(new RunnableThread());
        //Thread tt = new TradThread();

        rt.start();
        //tt.start();
        try {
            rt.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            System.out.println("Main thread wait is interrupted");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("MT-"+counter);
    }

}
```

It throws IllegalMonitorStateException as the main thread doesn't hold any monitor. Now in the same code if I change rt.wait() to rt.join() it works.

When I see how join is implemented it looks like it calls the wait() method. Now how is the call to wait from inside the join valid?

I would assume The Main thread when it calls rt.join() the code in the join method is being executed by the Main thread itself.

Please help me to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: ? join and wait are two different things and used for two very different purposes. For example, you can call `wait()` on *any* type of object and almost *never* call it on a Thread object, while `join()` is *only* called on threads. Your best bet is to read or re-read your chapter on this subject since it's fairly involved and will give you a much deeper understanding of the subject than anything that we can post.

Comment: Where are you checking how join is implemented? The Java source code?

Comment: Yes. From the Java source code

Comment: It's just using wait to put a pause in the joining of the threads, *if* a delay is desired. Here wait is called on a Thread object, on *itself*. And it itself holds the monitor since the method is synchronized using `this` as monitor (default use of synchronized).

Comment: Maybe the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963396/using-join-vs-wait-thread-java) could be helpful.

Comment: Did you notice the `synchronized` modifier in the method signature of the `join` method that does the work? `public final synchronized void join(long millis)`. That's why `wait` works inside the `join` method.

Comment: Erwin, Thanks I completely missed that. Now it makes sense so the main thread acquires a lock on the rt(child thread) object and could call wait. So would it be fair to assume that when the child thread has finished it will send out a notifyall() on itself?

Answer (score 0):

Thread.join() and Object.wait() are very different.

- t.join()

  Join current thread where you are behind thread t. So, current thread will not run until thread t finishes its work.
- o.wait()

  Release the lock of object o and pause current thread. So, current thread will not run until it obtains the lock of object o again by o.notify() or o.notifyAll() from other thread.
   Note: you must have obtained the lock of object o before invoking this method.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, in the join code, we have:

```
wait(0);
...
wait(delay);
```

in this case, this is the same as calling this.wait(). So to answer the question, the wait function being called is the object referenced by `rt` wait method.